# Idp Initiated sso with Itfoxtec

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, saml, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

According to the ItFoxTec documentation, I couldn't find information on implementing IDP-initiated SSO in the library, despite the presence of sample code for SP-initiated SSO.
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebApp

Answer (score 1):

You are right, IDP-initiated SSO is only documented in code. You can also find a .NET Core version at https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/IdPInitiatedController.cs